# publish a nuget package from a copy

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package

It seems my team mates have turned off their nuget server and gone on holidays.
I need a temporary work around so that my Azure Dev Ops build does not fail when restoring the nuget packages.

I have a local copy of the package at

C:\Users\kirst.nuget\packages\mypackagetemp

Which I want to publish to a temporary feed.

I read the instructions [on publishing a package from the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/publish?view=azure-devops) but am confused about step 6
Surely I dont need to set up the Project and restore packages as I already have the .nupkg

I tried the command

```
c:\nuget\nuget.exe push -Source "TempFeed" -ApiKey az mypackagetemp.nupkg
```

but got an error

> unable to load the service index for source
>   https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/mycompany/myproject/_packageing/TempFeed/nuget/v3/index.json

When I repeat the command I get a request for credentials
When I put in the credentials I connect to Azure Dev Ops with they do not work.

[Update]

I was prompted for credentials.. reading up on it... so confusing.

[Update]

I upgraded nuget.exe from 5.1.0.6013 to the latest version 5.4.0.6315 This time I got a UI to log in and the message

> Your package was pushed

However when the devops pipeline build runs I het a message

```
unable to load the service index for source
https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/mycompany/myproject/_packageing/TempFeed/nuget/v3/index.json
```

I guess I need to create an index.json file somehow.

My project is using a mynuget.config that has the following in the packagesources

```
 <add key="TempPackage" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/mycompany/_packaging/myfeed/nuget" />
```

[Update]

I changed mynuget.config to have

```
  <add key="TempPackage" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/mycompany/_packaging/myfeed/nuget/v3/index.json" />
```

Now the dev ops build shows the message

> Failed to retrieve information about 'Serilog.Enrichers.Thread'
>   from remote source
>   'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/mycompany/_packaging/myfeed/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id="Serilog.Enrichers.Thread'',
>   response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).)

My solution does use Serilog. I don't think the 3rd party package uses it.

[Update]

The next time I built I got a different error looking for WindowsAzure.Storage

I seem to get a different file causing the error each time I build the pipeline.

My project artifacts does have 2 feeds. The needed files are in the unselected feed.

[Update]

I tried editing mynuget.config to use index.json however I get a build error

> The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Unable to load
>   the service index for source
>   https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/mycompany/_packaging/myfeed/nuget/v3/index.json.
>   Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found - The
>   feed with ID 'MyFeed' doesn't exist

[Update]

Because the new feed was project based I edited mynuget.config to have

```
  <add key="TempPackage" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/mycompany/myproject/_packaging/myfeed/nuget/v3/index.json" />
```

Now it works!

Comment: See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops), if you use nuget restore task or similar tasks, we can determine the `feedstouse`, `select`(use devops feed+nuget.org) or `config`(custom nuget.config file). And for the error you get, it means 401 Unauthorized. So it's a permission-related issue.

Comment: You can use the `select` way, and navigate to Artifacts=>feed settings=>permissions=>add user/groups=>add your `current projectName build service` as owner role to make sure your build have access to get the packages from your feed.

Comment: my temp feed is project scoped. I wonder if it needs to be organizationaly scoped

Comment: 1.If your temp feed and current build pipeline belongs to same project, then it should work. If your temp feed belongs to Project A while the build pipeline belongs to Project B, you should make sure Project A has added the `Project B build service account` as member so that project B's build pipeline can access feed from Project A. 2.And see my update in answer, you could use the select way instead of mynuget.config when configuring the restore task (using UI) , click the dropdown list of `USe packages from Azure Artifacts/tfs feed`, if you can find the required feed there or not?

Comment: My tempfeed belonged to the project but I still needed to mention the project name in mynuget.config. Perhaps this is because the project also used a company wide package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure Devops web portal, for your current project, go `Artifacts` tab and make sure your packages like `mypackagetemp.nupkg` are available there.

[image]

For me, I have custom `LibraryCore.nupkg` pushed there. Now let's click the `Connect to feed` settings, choose `nuget.exe` and you can see:

[image]

Copy exactly same content to your own `mynuget.config` file. Then your build pipeline can access your published `mypackagetemp.nupkg`.

> Failed to retrieve information about 'Serilog.Enrichers.Thread' from
>   remote source
>   'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/mycompany/_packaging/myfeed/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id="Serilog.Enrichers.Thread'',
>   response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).)
>
> The next time I built I got a different error looking for
>   WindowsAzure.Storage

These packages(`Serilog.Enrichers.Thread`,`WindowsAzure.Storage` and ...) are all available in nuget.org, so you should also make sure you've add nuget.org as package source in your config file:

[image]

**In addition:**

According to your description, you only need to use your custom devops feed and other packages from `nuget.org`, apart from using your `mynuget.config`, you could configure your `nuget restore` task like this:

[image]

Choose devops feed directly(second red line) by `Feeds I select here` instead of Feeds in my `Nuget.config`. And check the `Use packages from nuget.org` checkbox. Then you can access the packages in custom feed and nuget.org during build.

Comment: I have nuget.org in mynuget.config. I aren't sure why I need to create index.json for myProjectSamples  or how to make it

Comment: @KirstenGreed Why you try to create index.json manually? Since you've pushed the package successfully, you can then use the URL-format `xxx/index.json`, we don't really need to create it on our own... You just need to follow my steps above to make sure what Url you need to copy to your MyNuget.config file. Also, i guess your error occurs in nuget restore step, you can check your log there and in the end of the log, you can see something like `feeds used`, make sure your mynuget.config works to provide correct feeds.

Comment: Lance Do you have instructions on how to create and push the index.json?

Comment: @KirstenGreed Sorry I have no idea how to create and push the index.json manually... And I'm sure that we don't need to create index.json file manually for devops feed :-(  See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-nuget?view=azure-devops), once we created one feed named `myfeed` in devops artifacts, then devops use URL `https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/OrgnizationName or whatever/_packaging/feedname/nuget/v3/index.json` to **represents** this feed. There's no need to create index.json file... Devops help us do this already, we just use it.

Comment: For `I guess I need to create an index.json file somehow.`:   The error `unable to load the service index for source` normally indicates permission issue. That shouldn't be the reason that you need to create an index.json file :-(  Follow my steps in answer and you'll find the correct URL(It should ends with xxx\index.json, see pic2's project setup)... Hope it helps:-)