# Build specific Visual studio project under project solution using Msbuild and devenv

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, devenv

I have Visual studio project solution which has multiple .csproj. Each .csproj has some reference libraries.The project settings are made in such a way the reference libraries are built first and then .csproj is built. This works as expected when i run it in visual studio IDE. But when i try to execute using msbuild i'm getting an error saying target doesn't exist. Gone through many posts related to this issue ,tried possible things.But didn't built.Looks like i might be doing something silly or missing something in the settings.

Also tried using devenv from commandline. With this option i dont see any error but at same time the project doesnt build.I dont see any message after execution of command.Im using visual studio 2015

```
Here is my project structure
 Poject.sln
   ProjectA
   porjectB
   projectC
   Libraries
      libA
      libB

msbuild "project.sln" target:"D:\Projects\Source\Demo\ProjectA\ProjectA.csproj" /t:build 
 "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:platform=x86"

I see the below error
"D:\project.sln" (D:\Projects\Source\Demo\ProjectA\;build target) (1) ->
 D:\project.sln.metaproj : error MSB4057: The target "D:\Projects\Source\Demo\ProjectA" does not exist in the project. [D:\project.sln]

Here is the command used using devenv
devenv.exe "project.sln" /build Debug /project `"D:\Projects\source\Demo\Applications\ProjectA\ProjectA.csproj" /projectconfig Debug

 After executing the above its doesnt build and i dont see any error too.
```

Comment: I figured out the issue with devenv command line build.Actually the code is building but it wont show the console output.As there is no console output  i felt the code is not building.  Using devenv there is a commandline option  /out  .Using this the output can be captured to file.     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" "D:\Projects\project.sln" /Rebuild "Debug|AnyCPU" /project "D:\Projects\projectA\projectA.csproj" /projectconfig Debug /out "D:\Projects\Error.txt"

Comment: with devenv on command line the execution stops this may lead to confusion.Actually the code gets build in the background. So its better to use devenv.com with same command line options .We can see the cursor blinking and gives us a feel the build is in progress. Can anyone tell  me how to print the logs on console.Are there are any commands for it.                    The MSbuild is still a puzzle for me. Hoping someone point my mistake in using MSbuild

Comment: To use msbuild, you don't need to use that format. `cd` to the folder where the `ProjectA.csproj` exists, and then `msbuild ProjectA.csproj /t:build 
 /p:Configuration=Debug /p:platform=x86` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

> error MSB4057: The target "D:\Projects\Source\Demo\ProjectA" does not
>   exist in the project.

The error indicates your path in command is not valid and project.sln can't recognize the path. So you actually meet one path-related issue. And you should pass the `ProjectA` to the targets argument instead of `ProjectA.csproj`! More details see tip3 in **For MSBuild**.

**For MSBuild:**

1.If you're only trying to build ProjectA and its reference libraries.

Navigate(`cd`) to path where `ProjectA.csproj` exists, and then use command `msbuild ProjectA.csproj /t:build /p:Configuration=Debug /p:platform=x86`

Also you can directly use command `msbuild AbsolutePath\ProjectA.csproj /t:build /p:Configuration=Debug /p:platform=x86`. It's not necessary to use `"` to cover the path and arguments.

(ProjectA.csproj file should have definitions about the reference to those two library projects, so `msbuild ProjectA.csproj` will build those two projects first. You don't need to specify the xx.sln in your command.)

2.If you're trying to build whole solution(all the projects):

```
msbuild project.sln /t:build /p:Configuration=xxx /p:platform=xxx
```

Navigate to solution folder when you run above command, or use `absolutepath\project.sln` with that command.

3.When you want to build specific projects(more than one) in solution:

Check [How to: Build Specific Targets in Solutions By Using MSBuild.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-specific-targets-in-solutions-by-using-msbuild-exe?view=vs-2015). Since you're only build ProjectA, you don't  need to use this format. For example: Only when you need to build both ProjectA and ProjectB, but not build ProjectC... You can use command like:

```
msbuild xxx.sln /t:NotInSlnfolder:Build;NewFolder\InSolutionFolder:Build
```

Pay attention to the path when you use this format. Whether your project is in solution folder can affect the build result a lot ! And, the **direct** cause of your issue, this command's `targets` argument needs one `ProjectName` as input instead of `ProjectName.csproj`.

**For Devenv command:**

1.I always use VS2017 and VS2019,so I'm not certainly sure if VS2015's devenv related command has big difference from VS2017's or VS2019's. But according to details from [this VS2017 document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches?view=vs-2017#devenv-switch-syntax):

*Commands that begin with devenv are handled by the devenv.com utility, which delivers output through standard system streams, such as stdout and stderr.
Alternatively, commands that begin with devenv.exe can use the same switches, but the devenv.com utility is bypassed. Using devenv.exe directly **prevents output from appearing on the console**.*

I think that's why you don't see any message after execution of command. You should use `devenv.com` command to see the output in console. And it's by design that `devenv.exe` will prevents output from appearing on the console.

2.The following command builds the project `CSharpWinApp`, using the `Debug` project build configuration within `MySolution`.

```
devenv "%USERPROFILE%\source\repos\MySolution.sln" /build Debug /project "CSharpWinApp\CSharpWinApp.csproj" /projectconfig Debug
```

More details about `devenv` reference please check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/build-devenv-exe?view=vs-2015#example).

**In addition:**

1.Looks like you have one strange project structure. I checked your error message above and it seems your several projects(xx.csproj) are not under Solution(xx.sln) folder. Just a suggestion, the normal folder structure for VS2015 is always:

```
Solution folder
     xx.sln
     ProjectA folder
         ProjectA.csproj
     ProjectB folder
         ProjectB.csproj
```

2.For most of the projects, build using `msbuild` is more powerful and convenient than build using `devenv`. So if you don't have special reason, I recommend using `Msbuild`, the build engine of VS.

Hope all above helps to resolve your issue and puzzle. Let me know if your issue persists:)

Comment: Lance,Thank you for reply. Actually my project is same as what you explained,its type mistake from my side.            With solution provided by you at least it solved  target doesn't exist issue. But for some strange reason still the build fails. This is failing because msbuild doesn't find the reference libraries. But the same project builds perfectly fine with IDE

Comment: @chandankumar For `msbuild doesn't find the reference libraries`, see [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315915/am-i-not-allowed-to-edit-my-own-question), you can edit your question(post) by `edit` option to share more details about the new error message you get. How do you reference the libraries? Using Project Dependency or Project reference? I'm interested about this issue and willing to help, but more details could be better :)

Comment: if i edit my post i may loose  the actual issue statement. How do i make sure  that first issue was resolved and then ran in to different issue. Please let me know if there is way to keep track of whole issue statments that occurs during this process.

Comment: The edit I mean is to add updated issue in question instead of deleting the original issue. Check the format of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59620613/publish-a-nuget-package-from-a-copy/59621555#59621555), we can add Update1, Update2... in question to track the whole issue during this process. And according to your comment above, I'm sure the new issue occurs when msbuild can't recognize dependence relationship between ProjectA and library projects, for this, I need to know how your projectA reference that library in csproj...

Comment: In addition, please share details about the error message of new issue... And your first issue is about correct format of msbuild command-line, this new issue has nothing to do with that, the new issue could be related to your definitions in xx.csproj file and the paths of these projects.