# Build specific projects with devenv

Tags: build, visual-studio-2019, devenv

I have the following folder structure for a VS2019 solution/project:

```
Solution_folder\
   my_solution.sln
   cpp_project\
      my_cpp_project.vcproj
   ifort_project\
      my_ifort_project.vfproj
   ...
   ...
```

and I want to build specific projects from this solution using the command prompt.

Following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59833828/9173295), as well as the [MS docs guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/project-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019)
I tried the following:

```
devenv %path_to_sln_folder%\my_solution.sln /build Release /project .\ifort_project\my_ifort_project.vfproj /projectconfig Release
```

Also tried other variations according to the documentation (eg reference the name of the project only or pass the absolute path of the project). However, I always get the following error:

```
The operation could not be completed

Use:
devenv  [solutionfile | projectfile | folder | anyfile.ext]  [switches]

The first argument for devenv is usually a solution file, project file or a folder.
You can also use any other file as the first argument if you want to have the
file open automatically in an editor. When you enter a project file, the IDE
looks for an .sln file with the same base name as the project file in the
parent directory for the project file. If no such .sln file exists, then the
IDE looks for a single .sln file that references the project. If no such single
.sln file exists, then the IDE creates an unsaved solution with a default .sln
file name that has the same base name as the project file.

Command line builds:
devenv solutionfile.sln /build [ solutionconfig ] [ /project projectnameorfile [ 
/projectconfig name ] ]
Available command line switches:

/Build                  Builds the solution or project with the specified solution
                        configuration. For example "Debug". If multiple platforms
                        are possible, the configuration name must be enclosed in quotes
                        and contain platform name. For example: "Debug|Win32".
/Clean                  Deletes build outputs.
/Command                Starts the IDE and executes the command.
/Deploy                 Builds and then deploys the specified build configuration.
/DoNotLoadProjects      Opens the specified solution without loading any projects.
/Edit                   Opens the specified files in a running instance of this
                        application. If there are no running instances, it will
                        start a new instance with a simplified window layout.
/LCID                   Sets the default language in the IDE for the UI.
/Log                    Logs IDE activity to the specified file for troubleshooting.
/NoVSIP                 Disables the VSIP developer's license key for VSIP testing.
/Out                    Appends the build log to a specified file.
/Project                Specifies the project to build, clean, or deploy.
                        Must be used with /Build, /Rebuild, /Clean, or /Deploy.
/ProjectConfig          Overrides the project configuration specified in the solution
                        configuration. For example "Debug". If multiple platforms are
                        possible, the configuration name must be enclosed in quotes
                        and contain platform name. For example: "Debug|Win32".
                        Must be used with /Project.
/Rebuild                Cleans and then builds the solution or project with the
                        specified configuration.
/ResetSettings          Restores the IDE's default settings, optionally resets to
                        the specified VSSettings file.
/ResetSkipPkgs          Clears all SkipLoading tags added to VSPackages.
/Run                    Compiles and runs the specified solution.
/RunExit                Compiles and runs the specified solution then closes the IDE.
/SafeMode               Launches the IDE in safe mode loading minimal windows.
/Upgrade                Upgrades the project or the solution and all projects in it.
                        A backup of these files will be created as appropriate. Please
                        see Help on 'Visual Studio Conversion Wizard' for more
                        information on the backup process.

Product-specific switches:

/debugexe       Open the specified executable to be debugged. The remainder of
                the command line is passed to this executable as its arguments.
/diff           Compares two files.  Takes four parameters:
                SourceFile, TargetFile, SourceDisplayName(optional),
                TargetDisplayName(optional)
/TfsLink        Opens Team Explorer and launches a viewer for the
                provided artifact URI if one is registered.
/useenv         Use PATH, INCLUDE, LIBPATH, and LIB environment variables
                instead of IDE paths for VC++ builds.

To attach the debugger from the command line, use:
        VsJITDebugger.exe -p <pid>
```

I must say that just by removing the part from `/project` onwards, the build starts ok and finishes without errors, but it is not what I want.

It strikes me as odd, as I believe I'm following the documentation correctly, yet the error message suggests I don't? Also, it doesn't seem to be solution- or project-specific as it's happening with other solutions/projects.

Am I missing anything obvious here?

Thanks